# Fatal Error: 'Declaration of Zend_Pdf_FileParserDatasource_File::__contruct() must be compatible

Tags: zend-framework, magento, cakephp-1.3

Does anyone got this error?

```
Fatal Error: 'Declaration of Zend_Pdf_FileParserDatasource_File::__contruct() must be compatible with Zend_Pdf_FileParderDatasource::__construct() in /var/www/abc/app/vendors/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource/File.php
```

I've googled a lot but still not find out the way to fix this bug.

Comment: Hi Simon, If you have got the answer please maek it answered by selecting the correct answer.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer to help others identify the correct answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can  change the constructor function of `lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php`

```
 abstract public function __construct();
```

to

```
 abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```

and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried commenting out __construct and __destruct abstract methods in Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php

```
//    abstract public function __construct();
//    abstract public function __destruct();
```

It worked for me.

This error has something to do with inheritance in latest versions of PHP.

Comment: Is this a bug of Magento or Zend ?

Comment: This is a Zend bug. Have a look at e.g. http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12093

Answer (score 3):

At the moment I write this answer, all you need to do is upgrade your Zend_PDF library. The bug has been fixed and ff you here because you are using Magento and has faced this issue, just do the upgrade and it should be fine. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears to be happening for me on Magento installs on **PHP 5.4** and above. I corrected it by using Afroz Alam's answer of changing

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

to

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```

in the file `lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php`

Comment: Great to know it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Change: abstract public function __construct(); to abstract public function __construct($filePath);
Location:lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php

This works for me.